# index.ctp is styled but rest of the pages are not

Tags: php, css, formatting, styles

index page is styled while rest of the pages are not.When i checked cascading style sheets(CSS) files in browser, I was surprised to see those CSS files are not accessible for all pages except of Index.ctp. All pages are in same folder and same links are given to access cascading style sheets then why those CSS files are not accessible for other pages.I tried enough to resolve this but could not. i tried to fin solution of this on Google but can't find any solution.

Comment: controler name is FrontsController and folder iname is Fronts. css and js files are in css, js folders respectively. i using this way to add css file in about page.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the stylesheets on `default.ctp` layout in `View/layout` not on `index.ctp`.

Comment: i include this two links in default.ctp but nothing is changed.. href is ok or need to be changed? <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">

Comment: are they accessible??where do you keep them?

Answer (score 0):

in your comment

controler name is FrontsController and folder iname is Fronts. css and js files are in css, js folders respectively. i using this way to add css file in about page.  –  user3623305 35 mins ago
add a comment

change path for css to be href="/css/reset.css"

Anyways it better to include your css files using html helper like this

```
echo $this->Html->css('css_name');
```

if your css file is at app/webroot/css, and it's name is main.css, use

```
echo $this->Html->css('main');
```

For more information look here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css